# Ordeals and their weight on Dharmashastras

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, dharmasutra, morality, ordeals

Ordeals or divine tests were prescribed based on Dharmashastras, but is this fair in regards to running a kingdom? Why was the logic behind them from a legal and justice standpoint and a theological/philosophical standpoint? Were ordeals the first or last course of action in a trial in case the defendant exhausted all other options? Why is it generally Ordeals for lower Varnas are more painful and hard/impossible to overcome couldn't this be a loophole for higher Varnas to escape punishment? This is one of the few parts of Dharmashastras I just do not understand.